# Can I check which objects got saved if saveAll returned an error?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm using `beforeSave` to check for duplicates. As it was pointed out, if you refuse a duplicate you must return a `response.error()`

This would cause a `saveAll()` to fail, and the failure callback will be called. Is there any way of checking which objects were saved successfully and which failed?